# SQLCLR Aggregate: no message about NULL values being eliminated

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, sqlclr

when I do

```
SELECT SUM(some_field) FROM some_table
```

the result is a single record/field with a number in it. Additionally, there will be a message send to the client along the lines of `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` in case `some_field` has a `NULL` value in the table somewhere. Only when they all are `NULL` (or the table is empty) it will return `NULL`.

I'm currently in the process of writing my own SqlUserDefinedAggregate and although things work as expected, it does **NOT** show me this message when one of the values passed turns out to be NULL. The outcome of the function is still correct, but there is no warning. First I assumed I might have to *pipe* this manually in the `Terminate()` method, but alas, SQLCLR then throws me an `InvalidOperationException` saying `Data acces is not allowed in this context.`

Any hints?

Comment: I was curious about this recently myself and had a thought to try something but never got around to it. What happens if you set the IsInvariantToNulls property on the aggregate to false?

Comment: I already had it set to false.Out of curiosity I set it to true, but I don't see any difference.

Comment: Are you looking to alter the behavior of the aggregate based on the presence (or conversely, absence) of nulls? Or do you just want the message?

Comment: I'm mostly trying to emulate the 'standard' aggregations as closely as possible. So if I can get that message there, either automatically by the SQL-engine, or manually by means of some code of mine I'd be a happy camper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aggregate is discarding `NULL`s then the `IsInvariantToNulls` property should definitely be set to `true` else you might get unexpected results sometimes, as stated on the MSDN page for [SqlUserDefinedAggregateAttribute.IsInvariantToNulls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedaggregateattribute.isinvarianttonulls):

> Used by the query processor, this property is **true** if the aggregate is invariant to nulls. That is, the aggregate of S, {NULL} is the same as aggregate of S. For example, aggregate functions such as MIN and MAX satisfy this property, while COUNT(*) does not.
>
> Incorrectly setting this property can result in incorrect query results. This property is not an optimizer hint; it affects the plan selected and the results returned by the query.

And a UDA is a function so there is no `SqlContext.Pipe` to use. And even if there was, the `Terminate` method isn't an appropriate place to handle this since it executes for every group. The warning you are seeing when using `SUM`, however, is an ANSI warning and is displayed once for the query, not per group.

So, if SQL Server isn't displaying the warning then there likely isn't anything you can do about it. I assume that SQL Server isn't using the `IsInvariantToNulls` property as a means of knowing if it should display the message or not because it is not guaranteed to be accurately set.

And personally, I find this to be a benefit since, in my opinion, the "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate" warning is entirely not helpful, yet if you want to get rid of it you need to use `ISNULL()` to inject a value that won't influence the result (e.g. `0` in the case of `SUM`), or turn off ALL ANSI warnings, in which case you disable some warnings that are sometimes helpful.

Comment: All of that is true indeed. I was just trying to stay as close as possible to the 'original' behaviour.

Comment: @deroby I get it. I just don't see any possible mechanism in any of SQLCLR that would allow for that, at least not without running the entire query through a CLR stored procedure, but that is just silly. Also, even if you were able to print a message, you would have to _not_ display it if the session property of `ANSI_WARNINGS` was set to `OFF`. Sure, you could test `@@OPTIONS`, but no way to SQL Server wouldn't know that you are doing that. So this really is something that the database engine needs to handle by itself.